# Is wrapping my whole php website within isLoggedIn() and hasPermission() considered bad coding practice?

Tags: php, json, performance, authentication

So I am coding a web application. Everyone may register an account, however without being approved by an admin it shall not be possible to access the website.

I tried it like this:

```
if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
        if($user->hasPermission('user')) {
                //my whole website
        }
echo "Admin hasn't approved your account yet;
}
```

**isLoggedIn()** checks whether the user is logged in or not, **hasPermission()** checks for the user permission in a json string saved in my database.

Is putting my whole website within those two if-statements considered bad coding practice and is there a better way to do this or is my approach fine?

Comment: I think it might reaaly be opinion based but I think that wrapping everything in one if block might add useless indentation and make the code harder to read.
You might wanna put these tests only at the beggining of the code and do something like `if($user->isLoggedIn()) { 
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Admin hasn't approved your account yet; 
    return 
}` and then put the rest of your code after.

Comment: I always just use `die("ERROR...");` on failure to meet conditions because otherwise as @kerwan noted, the indentation is a bit messed up.

Comment: I would say making OOP based solution for that purpose would be much cleaner and efficient way. and then u can check for permission in constructor! that's my opinion tho, there might be some better solutions!

Comment: @Matt Is doing it using die() safe? And any hints on how to make a OOP based solution? (Just googled but didnt find anything useful)

Comment: @NikushJorjoliani what would an OOP based solution look like? Any hints? Couldnt find anything on google?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! @kerwan

Comment: @Noni check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Foo { 

    function __construct() { 
        //do ur permission check here 
    } 


    function some_custom_func() { 
        //do ur action here
    } 
}
```

custom function wont be executed without first executing construct function!